# ROS Answers SE migration: rtabmap+3d map

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
i used rtabmap to created 3d map from environment. i used stereo camera for this. my question is that, in rtabmap, How is the 3D map created for stereo camera? it is feature based or area based? in other words, What is a 3D map creating theory?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297230/rtabmap+3d-map/) by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-23**:
@zahra.kh you have a lot of questions with answers but you haven't marked them as correct, can I ask that you please go through your questions and do so to the ones that solved your problem? This will let future users know what worked. Specifically #q282985 and #q282399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For each node, a disparity image is created using cv:StereoBM(), then projected to create a cloud. The clouds are then assembled the same way than clouds created from RGB-D cameras.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0